# Efficiently chunk large vector into a vector of vectors

Tags: vector, rust, iterator, slice

I want to chunk a large vector into a vector of vectors. I know about `chunks()`, but am not sure of the best way to go from the iterator to a 2D `Vec`. I have found the following to work, but is there a better way to write this?

```
let v: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3];
let v_chunked: Vec<Vec<i32>> = v.chunks(3).map(|x| x.to_vec()).collect();

println!("{:?}", v_chunked); // [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5031d4d0e43470242b8304d483967a25

An operation similar to this is one of the slowest parts of my program after profiling and I was wondering how to improve it.

Comment: I don't see the problem.

Comment: You could create a vector of slices or write/use a strided array type. *Is there a better way?* is a rather open question. Can you specify why this approach is not good enough?

Comment: The question is way to broad. I guess that the real question is: what is the best way to represent a 2D vector? The solution, IMHO, it to wrap a single vector and to add some methods to abstract it as being 2D.

Comment: You will have N + 2 allocations, with N being the number of elements of `v_chuncked`. You can have only 2 allocations by returning Vec<[i32; 3]> instead of Vec<Vec<i32>>. See https://godbolt.org/z/4Z2iww.

Comment: As a new Rust user I gravitated towards defining my struct with a vec of vecs because I don’t know the exact size of the collection to be chunked into it at compile time. I do know it will have millions of elements and I need to perform this hundreds of times though. I will explore the vec of slices approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If a `Vec<Vec<i32>>` is what you really want then this is a pretty good way of doing it. Any other approach (excluding `unsafe` code, see below) is unlikely to be significantly faster or use noticeably less memory. Regardless of the actual code, each nested `Vec` is a new memory allocation and all the data will be need to copied - and that's essentially all that your code does.

A more "Rusty" way to represent a 2D structure like this is a `Vec` of slices into the original data. That way you don't do any copying and no new allocations.

```
let v_slices: Vec<&[i32]> = v.chunks(3).collect();

println!("{:?}", v_slices); // [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

---

<sub>**Edit:** I did have an [extra bit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54420325/5) here with some `unsafe` code that would transform a `Vec<i32>` into a `Vec<Vec<i32>>` without reallocating. However, it has been pointed out that it still has Undefined Behaviour, and that the problem is fundamentally [not fixable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa0hy.png)</sub>

Comment: Additional note if it's helpful to anyone: the last chunk can be of a smaller size than the defined chunk size if the `v.len() % chunk_length != 0` . I wanted chunks of exactly equal sizes (listening on a channel), and waiting for the next batch to complete to complete worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the comments, I found storing the data as a 1D `Vec` to be much more efficient. Then to deal with it conveniently I use `chunks` and work with the `Vec` of slices as needed within the function bodies using the data.